# Can not reconnect port in official mxGraph example

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

I am quite new to mxGraph library. I was looking at their official examples an like one https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/ports.html , which fits quite good to my planned project. But what I still dont know, why user can not reconnect already connected edge to other port. Can you please tell me the way I should look. I think in that example there is some missing part to able reconnect edge only to port and not to base vertex.

Right know, when you want to change some connected port you must delete connection (edge) and make new one. I would like to able reconnect edge to another port as it is standard with default vertex.